# How to replace NaN to 0 in one column of excel data extracted with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm a student who only knows a small part of the basics of python, and I'm posting a question to solve a problem in a stats assignment.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPaRK.png

I need to extract values from these excel data and output them as graphs in python.

```
import numpy as np   
import pandas as pd   
from IPython.display import display   

%matplotlib inline


pd.options.display.max_rows = 13
pd.set_option('display.max_columns',750)


file_name = 'C:\last_amb_hour_time.xls'


df = pd.read_excel(file_name, header=6, index_col=0)   
dfdate = pd.read_excel(file_name, header=6, index_col=0, usecols='A')   
dfpm10 = pd.read_excel(file_name, header=6, index_col=0, usecols='C')   
dfpm25 = pd.read_excel(file_name, header=6, index_col=0, usecols='E')   
dfozon = pd.read_excel(file_name, header=6, index_col=0, usecols='G')   
dfno2 = pd.read_excel(file_name, header=6, index_col=0, usecols='I')   
dfco = pd.read_excel(file_name, header=6, index_col=0, usecols='K')   
dfso2 = pd.read_excel(file_name, header=6, index_col=0, usecols='M')
```

Currently, the data has been extracted in this way. But  many blanks in the excel data are treated as NaN, so the graph cannot be output.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sayMh.png

like this

I want to replace NaN in one column to 0. However, if I use `dfpm10 = df.fillna(0)` or replace syntax, the entire excel data is output instead of just one column.

I want to know which command to use to replace NaN data with 0 in one extracted column.

It seems like a simple question, but since I've never learned python properly, I can't solve it even after trying for hours. Sorry.

Comment: Simply subset the `dataframe df['colname'] = df['colname'].fillna(0)`

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand well.
Do I have to put the column name of Excel itself in the same way as col2? Or do I need to set the column names in advance?

Answer (score 1):

You should add the name of the column you want to change like this

```
dfpm10 = df    
dfpm10['COLUMN NAME HERE'] = dfPM10['COLUMN NAME HERE'].fillna(0)
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand well. 
I'm not sure how to name the columns. As you can see from the excel image, it is difficult to set the first row as a name because the format is like that.

Comment: You can try using that: print("Dataframe columns:", df.columns) and after you saw the name of the column you can change it if you want using that: df = df.rename(columns={"OLD_NAME":"NEW_NAME"})

Comment: `print("Dataframe columns:", df.columns)
dfpm10 = df.rename(columns={"Unnamed: 2":"pm10"})
dfpm10['pm10'] = dfpm10['pm10'].fillna(0)`   
Thanks, I have successfully entered the code like this to name the columns.   
However, even if follow this method, when I use `display(dfpm10)`, the entire excel data is printed. Only in the specified column's NaN values are replaced with 0.   
Can't I print only one column when I do `display(dfpm10)` according to the previously entered `dfpm10 = pd.read_excel(file_name, header=6, index_col=0, usecols='C')` format?